# efficiently blocking comments that contain banned urls

Tags: php

I have a fairly *family-friendly* website that is starting to gain a bit of traction. Due to the traction, it is becoming very difficult to moderate comments that might contain links to scams, spam or pornographic material. To combat this, I thought it might be a good idea to create a **PHP** script to automatically moderate comments.

Something like this is what was going through my head:

```
function isValidComment($string){
    // json file containing a list of banned websites
    $banned = json_decode(file_get_contents("banned.json"));
    foreach($banned as $site){
        // if string contains banned website return invalid
        if(strpos($string, $site) !== false){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The only problem is that this list has about *2.2 million* websites in it. Iterating over every single one of these websites and checking if one of them are within the string would be extremely taxing on the server.

My question is: what is a more efficient approach to doing this? I don't want to blow up my server every time someone makes a comment - which at this point is roughly 20 comments per minute (roughly 0.33 per second).

All help is appreciated.

Comment: At some point some alternative architecture will start to make sense. E.g. you don't need to check every comment as it's being submitted, but instead you have a background worker process every new comment after it has been submitted and perhaps delete comments after the fact. A dedicated worker can do that at its own pace, and you can even scale the number of workers. Such a worker could be persistent and have the list of bad words in memory, instead of needing to load it from JSON every time. Look into queue-worker solutions.

Comment: @deceze Love this comment. Do you know if there are any libraries available which could show me how to do this type of thing - or, even better, are you willing to post an answer which will point me in the right direction? Cheers!

Comment: It's a bit outdated but start with something like [Gearman](http://gearman.org) as an example. The biggest problem is that you probably can't run this on a common shared server; if you're in that situation that'll be the biggest hurdle.

Comment: My 2 cents :
1/ can you use a database ? Search will be way more efficient
2/ it may be more efficient to extract sites from the comment and search them in your banned list instead of searching every site of your list in the comment
3/ small detail but you have to handle urls variants like http, https, with or without www. It is not as simple as your example lets think it is

Comment: Also, maybe you can just start with a cronjob ?
Otherwise you can have a look at a queueing/messaging system like RabbitMq, it let you have a pool of worker to do stuff

Comment: An elegant way to do this is to have all comments submitted to a queue service (e.g. [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) or [Redis](https://redis.io/) job queue). Then have a daemon process (a.k.a. "worker") to process it on another server. That way the frontend wouldn't notice the pain suffered by the worker :-)